# What can caused run time error in C besides array for uVA 11192 Group Reverse?

Tags: c, runtime-error

I don't know what caused my code to get run time error because the array needed for uVA 11192 is only [101] (minimum) and I don't use any pointer here.

```
int div = 1;
char arr[110];
while(div>0)
{
    scanf("%d",&div);
    getchar();

    scanf("%s",arr);
    getchar();

    len=strlen(arr);

    length=len/div;

    for(int i=1;i<=div;i++)
    {
        right = (length*i)-1;

        for(int j=length;j>=1;j--)
        {
            printf("%s",arr[j]);

            arr[j] = arr[102];
        }

        left = length*i;

        puts("");
    }

    left=0;
}
```

Comment: The way to find out is to do some debugging. Run the program in a debugger. At the  minimum it will tell you immediately which line triggers the error. You can also step thru the code and examine its state as much as you want/need.

Comment: `arr[102]` is probably used uninitialized, depending on the input. What is `len` and `length`? Think about what happens when you enter `0` for `div`.

Comment: `%s` in `printf` expects a `char *`, but `arr[j]` is a `char`.

Comment: You divide by `div` *before* testing it for `0`. Does a `0` mark the end of the data?

Comment: The [UVa 11192 question](https://onlinejudge.org/external/111/11192.pdf) states: *"Input is terminated by a line containing a single zero."*

Comment: Your array indices look very fishy.